# Can this cause deadlock? BeginInvoke() & thread.Join()

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, begininvoke

I have this code that many threads can call to update the GUI:

```
MethodInvoker del = () => { lblInfo.Text = tmp; };
lblInfo.BeginInvoke(del);
```

(lblInfo is created by the GUI thread)

I also have this method called at button click executed by the GUI thread:

```
public void Stop()
{
    isStopping = true;
    crawler.Join();
    foreach (Thread t in txtWorkers)
    {
        t.Join();
    }
    indexer.Join();     
    lblStatus.Text = "Stopped";
    lblInfo.Text = "";
}
```

1 time over 100 run the program deadlock at Stop button click. I was not debugging when i saw the deadlock so i can't be sure about the state of the various threads but i'm almost sure that all the threads i'm joining will eventually reach the point where they check for 
`isStopping` value and terminate. This leads me to think that there may be a problem with the `BeginInvoke` but can't really find it. It should be async so threads calling it (crawler & indexer) should not block. What happens if the GUI thread is executing `Stop()` and also must execute a call from `BeginInvoke`? Could this be the problem? Is there something i can't see about the thread i'm joining?

**EDIT:**
What the code looks like after the suggested changes:

```
public void Stop()
{
    /*
     ...disable GUI
     */

    isStopping = true; // Declared as volatile
    lblStatus.Text = "Stopping...";

    // Creating a thread that will wait for other threads to terminate
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {    
        crawler.Join();
        foreach (Thread t in txtWorkers)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
        indexer.Join();

        // Adjust UI now that all threads are terminated
        MethodInvoker del = () =>
        {
            /*
            ...enable GUI
            */
            lblStatus.Text = "Not Running";
            isStopping = false;
        };
        lblStatus.BeginInvoke(del);
    });
}
```

It seems to be working, i hope that deadlock is gone...

Comment: Have you tried with `lblInfo.Invoke(del)`?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria with such a rare problem, i can't just try and be happy because it worked once, also, it seem to me that using invoke can indeed cause a deadlock

Comment: Like Jon Skeet says, don't call blocking operations in GUI event handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't *think* it should be a problem, because you're using `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke` - the background threads will just proceed past that line without waiting for the GUI to catch up. If you're using `Control.Invoke` anywhere, that *could* cause a deadlock.

More importantly, using `Join` in your GUI thread is fundamentally a bad idea - the UI will be frozen until everything's finished. It would be better to disable any controls which could start anything new, set your `isStopping` flag, and then create a new thread to wait for all the threads to stop - and when all the threads have finished, *then* update the UI with `BeginInvoke` again. (If you're using .NET 4.5 you could also use an asynchronous method for this, creating and awaiting a task to wait for all the threads.)

Finally, if `isStopping` is just a `bool` field, there's no guarantee that your background threads will "see" the change from the UI thread. It's possible that making the field volatile would fix this, but the precise meaning of volatile scares me. An alternative would be to use the `Interlocked` class, or make it a property which obtains a lock for both reading and writing - that ensures appropriate memory barriers are in place.

Comment: No need for a new thread to wait for all the threads to stop.  They can BeginInvoke a 'done' message as their last operation before either terminating or looping around to wait on something. The GUI can count 'em out and count'em back in again when it gets the 'done' messages.

Comment: I thought that it wouldn't have been a problem joining in the main thread because the work that workers do after the bool is set is so few and i can't notice any freez but you're right. The thing about the bool not read correctly is all new to me... only the main thread writes it and a bool is atomic (isn't it?) so i thought "no problem". I guess i'll have to look at this memory barriers concept... thanks i'll be back to accept this answer as soon as i fully understand it.